# Angularjs: Break the string to next line after 100 characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im binding the expression `{{address}}` which might have more than 100 characters. I want to display characters which falls after 100 to next line using angularjs.

Let say , view.html

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <span>{{address}}</span>
</div>
```

and controller.js has

```
//Some code 
 $scope.address="bdfjhfj  jhgueih hdeiuheiu heiuheiuwheiqheiu heiwuhi";
```

I want to display characters more than 100 to display in next line . Thank You.

Comment: try use `{{address |limitTo:100}}`

Comment: @ThanhTùng but i also want remaining text to be align to next line as same as above

Comment: you can try use my answer below @SiddheshMishra

Comment: y for 100 characters??what is your actual requirement??

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  {{address | limittext}}
  <script>
    var app = angular.module("app", [])
      .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
        $scope.address = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
      })
      .filter("limittext", function() {
        return function(input) {
          var output = "";

          for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i = i + 100) {
            output = output + input.substring(i, i + 100) + '\n';
          }
          return output;
        }
      })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Created a filter which divides text by 100 characters.
hope this helps you.

Comment: '\n' is taking as space

Comment: @SiddheshMishra, copy the result text, from here and see it pasted in some editor/notepad having enough length to show 100 characters in single line.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use

```
<div>{{address | limitTo:100}}</div>
<div>{{address | limitTo:100:100}}</div>
<div>{{address | limitTo:100:200}}</div>
```

here is syntax

```
{{ object | limitTo : limit : begin }}
```

> limit: A number, specifying how many elements to return
>
> begin: Optional. A number specifying where to begin the limitation.
>   Default is 0

Comment: what if there are more than 200 characters?

Answer (score -1):

```
   $scope.newAddress='';
    while ( $scope.address.length > 100) {
        $scope.newAddress+=  $scope.address.substring(0, 100) + '<br>';
        $scope.address= $scope.address.substring(100);
      }
   $scope.newAddress+=$scope.address;
```

and

```
{{$scope.newAddress}}
```